# Grep 2 variables with a ":" in between

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, grep, quotes

I am currently stuck on this piece of code for a long time now. Below is my code.

```
if grep -ixqF $bookName:$authorName BookDB.txt
then echo "Book found"
else
echo "Book not found"
```

BookDB basically contains Book title and author information as shown below, where syntax is "Book-name:Author".

`Mary had a little nose:JamesPoppcock
Merry Christmas:Christ Sake
Kinky Asians:Walter Bedding`

However, the program always output "Book found", even if the book and author is not in the BookDB.txt. What I want from this program is that it will read in 2 user input, `$bookName` and `$authorName` and match it exactly (including the semi-colon) to the database.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Edit: The program always output "Book not found", instead of "Book found"

Comment: Upload your example file somewhere.

Comment: Hello! I uploaded the original text file here. http://txt.do/58ofn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote the variable expansion portion:

```
grep -ixqF "$bookName:$authorName" BookDB.txt
```

Without quoting the expansion is suffering from word splitting (and glob expansion) and only the first word is taken as a pattern to search and the rest are being treated as file name(s) along with `BookDB.txt`.

Comment: Hello! I just edited my program output. Apologies for the mistake. I tried adding the double quotes too, but the program still repeatedly output "Book not found" even if the book and author is in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I am thoroughly embarrassed by my own stupid mistake. To make things simpler i did not put up the original text file which contains 3 more parameters. I realised the problem with my code is the grep's -x argument, where it only find strings that matches the whole line.
After removing it, the program works fine.
It is only after [Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776858/cyrus) comment that I realised it is probably the problem with my original `BookDB.txt` .
Thank you all !!

Answer (score -1):

Changing your're if statement to below should resolve you're issue

`if [ "$(grep -ixF "$bookName:$authorName" BookDB.txt)" != "" ]`

As suggested by @heemayl, you need to use double quote around the variable.

Also, instead of using -q option of grep, you can simple compare the output with `!= ""`.

Comment: `grep` sets an exit code.  I believe that you will find that there is no advantage to putting grep _inside_ a command substitution _inside_ a test so that test can set an exit code.